# Raspberry Pi - Crontab task not running properly

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, arp

I have scheduled a task `arp -a` which runs once per hour, that scans my wi-fi network to save all the info about currently connected devices into a `scan.txt` file. After the scan, a python script reads the `scan.txt` and saves the data into a database.

This is what my `wifiscan.sh` script looks like:

```
cd /home/pi/python/wifiscan/
arp -a > /home/pi/python/wifiscan/scan.txt
python wifiscan.py
```

This is my crontab task:

```
#wifiscan
59 * * * * sh /home/pi/launcher/wifiscan.sh
```

If I run the `wifiscan.sh` file manually, all the process works perfectly; when it is run by the crontab, the `scan.txt` file is generated empty and the rest of the process works, but with no data, so I'm assuming that the problem lies in the `arp -a` command.

How is it possible that `arp -a` does not produce any output when it is run by crontab? Is there any mistakes I'm making?

Comment: In your Terminal, run `type arp` and it will tell you the full path to `arp`. Use that in your script. Your PATH is different in `crontab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark Setchell commented, I solved my problem by launching the command with its entire path (in this case, `/usr/sbin/arp`)